# web service reference in DLL

Tags: web-services, configuration

hope someone can help with something that is really budding me.

i have a smart client, a couple of web services and some DLL's.
the dll's are essentially forms and controls. the dll's reference the web services within themselves.

the problem i have is how to change the references to the web services IN THE DLL's dynamically as you would do if i was they resided in a web.config file.

i can set the web service reference behviour to dynamic and change the reference in the web config file and the new location is used. how fo i apply the same for teh DLL as tehy are binary and the windows app.config has no reference to the actual web services.

hope that is clear. i am really srumped and would appreciate any an all advice.

many thanks

Answer (score 4):

The DLLs will use the app.config file of their host application. For example if your smart client is called MySmartClient, then you could use MySmartClient.exe.config the same way you would use web.config to define web service urls.